# how to make different color within a heatmap

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, heatmap

Here is my data

```
df<- structure(list(name = structure(c(2L, 12L, 1L, 16L, 14L, 10L, 
9L, 5L, 15L, 4L, 8L, 13L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 11L), .Label = c("All", 
"Bab", "boro", "bra", "charli", "delta", "few", "hora", "Howe", 
"ist", "kind", "Kiss", "myr", "No", "TT", "where"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(1.251, -1.018, -1.074, -1.137, 1.018, 1.293, 1.022, 
    -1.008, 1.022, 1.252, -1.005, 1.694, -1.068, 1.396, 1.646, 
    1.016)), .Names = c("name", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```

I want to have very clear shade separation. 
if I want to make a heatmap with specific color, I do like this

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = 1,y = name, fill = value)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  ylab("") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low='red', high='blue')
```

It makes it red to blue. what I want is to make the **first 7 rows** for example **red to blue** and the rest **pink to black.**

Is this possible ?

Comment: Not obvious to me how to do this. One hack would be to set alpha and use geom_rect to give different background colours

Comment: By "first 7 rows", do you mean first 7 rows of `df`, or top 7 rows of the plot, or perhaps the bottom 7 rows?  One idea would be to have 2 plots and then lay them out using `grid`.

Comment: @Weihuang Wong top 7 rows of the plot

Comment: have you tried something with `scale_fill_manual(values=cols)` and then define cols as you like ... `cols = c( colorRampPalette(c("red","blue"))(n=7),colorRampPalette(c("pink","black"))(n=7) )`

Comment: @Amit no i did not, please make it as an answer . I will check it out!!!

Answer (score 1):

ggplot generally encourages one scale per data series, but if you really wanted different scales for different subsets of the values, here's one way to do it.

You say you want a different scale for the first 7 rows. Again, tying presentation to the data's position isn't a great practice, but let's suppose we create a "group" column. It's important that this column be numerical, since we'll be using it to "cheat" the values in the heatmap. So a set of group values that separate your distribution would be good:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- arrange(df, name) %>% 
    mutate(group = c(rep(-3, 7), rep(3, 9)))
```

The `fill` aesthetic then becomes `value - group`, and we use `scale_fill_gradientn` to assign colors:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = 1,y = name, fill = value - group)) + 
    geom_tile() + 
    ylab("") +
    scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c('black', 'pink', 'red', 'blue'))
```

Which gives you this plot:
[image]

Comment: thanks, give me some time, I will check it out and if it gives me the answer I will definelty accept it